# Calling dispatch in useEffect?

Tags: redux, react-redux, use-effect

At the moment I am simple calling it inside the useEffect hook, without having it as a dependency as I only want it to run once. This however gives `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'.` Should I add dispatch to the dependencies or is there a better practice for this?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(handleGetUser());
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dispatch function doesn't change between re-renders. The eslint warning isn't aware of what each function does and whether or not it will be recreated or not and hence it shows the warning to prompt the user if he/she has missed something

You can safely disable the warning in this case and not include dispatch as a dependency

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(handleGetUser());

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Even if you include dispatch as a dependency you will not see side-effects as dispatch will not change unless the library exposing it has a bug

Answer (score 2):

As @Shubham Khatri said, the dispatch function doesn't change between re-renders.

That means it is safe to add it to the dependency list and it won't make your code re-run:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(handleGetUser());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

The [official React guidance](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#to-change-the-dependencies-change-the-code) cautions against disabling the lint rule because it can easily lead to subtle bugs. It's better to write your effect in a way that makes the linter happy (and the linked docs give more guidance on how to do so in the general case).